# Openlayers specific: select a 'real centroid' point in a polygon that is always inside the polygon. Example L-shaped polygon

Tags: openlayers

In Openlayers 5+, how can I calculate the centroid of a polygon that is always inside the polygon?

It really doesn't matter how accurate the point is, as long as it is sufficient in the center of the polygon.

I know there are solutions for QGIS, but I need one for Openlayers v5+.

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon-Polygon.html#getInteriorPoint

Comment: Please promote as answer. This helped - an easy to use method gives the right result. Thank you.